# Long running background task in a Bottle application

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, bottle, background-task

I've been looking for a way to run a continuous background task in a Python Bottle application whilst simultaneously using Gevent for handling requests:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from time import sleep
from bottle import route, run

# run_background_function()
# ^^^^ starts a single background task that runs every few seconds
# and continues for the life of the whole Bottle application.

@route('/simple-request')
def simple_request():
    # a simple function that returns a rendered page and
    # is capable of serving multiple requests
    return rendered_page()

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, server='gevent')
```

I've read though many stackoverflow threads and 7 full tutorials thus far including Gevent, threading, celery, rabbitmq, redis and have no idea what I should be using to achieve this ability. Celery, RabbitMQ and Redis all seem insanely difficult and overkill for running this one background task, plus I'd prefer to stay with options in the Python standard library if possible.

The tutorials I've found so far start off very basic then suddenly leap into including 3rd party libraries, sockets, specific web frameworks etc. Is there no way of doing this just on the Python threading module?

Comment: celery, rabbitmq and redis are not insanely difficult. they may or may not be overkill for your case, depending on the details of your needs.

Comment: @scytale. Okay, maybe not insanely difficult but after attempting a number of tutorials and the getting started guides for those packages it's noticeable most claim a basic introduction with much more complex example code than it needs to be. For an example that doesn't do this and in two paragraphs explains a concept clearly (the queue/list explanation) see here: [Multithreading/Queues](http://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/)

Comment: the tutorials are aimed at a programmer who is familiar with basic programming concepts - they can't explain _everything_ - you'll just need to do more reading

Comment: I don't have a problem with basic programming concepts. These concepts are not really very basic and if they were there wouldn't be so many posts on SO asking about the same things, it's just that most posts on SO are application specific and many users find it difficult to rip the important code out to use it in another case scenario. Even some of the well-known authorities introduce concurrent/parallel processing with an indication that in Python it is not simple.

Comment: Why not just start a python Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with `multiprocessing` :

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def processor():
    setproctitle('%s - processor ' % (__file__,))

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        do_stuff()

my_processor = Process(target=processor)
```

Comment: Just before I try integrating this I presume I can just stick the my_processor call into the top of my Bottle application code and it won't prevent the rest of the application running with Gevent?

Comment: yes, it should be fine - you're not going to be using gevent inside `my_processor`, right?

Comment: and you'll need to add some code to clean up the worker on exit of your main loop

Comment: cleaning up is not a problem, just needed to make sure I could run that single process in the background, thank you.